# Burninate/retag [msdn] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[msdn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/msdn)

<strike>Not necessarily a burninate request because I'm not 100% sure if there are still cases where this tag makes sense.</strike> **Edit:** now a burninate/retag request.

I tried retagging [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25249306/waitable-timer-reset-period) from [msdn] to [winapi], but the author reverted it. Rather than get into a potential edit war, I wanted to understand better what the [msdn] tag really means.

IMO, questions regarding specific Windows functions (such as `CreateWaitableTimer`) should be tagged [winapi], since it *is* part of the win32 API, and questions regarding MSDN itself aren't really on topic.

As far as questions relating to MSDN tutorials, I feel they should be treated the same as questions referring to any other external tutorial - if there was a tag for every possible C tutorial, well...I'd rather not imagine such a situation. If it's a question about "is this MSDN code/documentation wrong", then maybe a better tag would suffice? If nothing else, all other questions should be retagged/closed/etc, and the wiki updated with something like "note: for questions regarding Windows functions, see [winapi]".

<strike>What exactly should happen with this tag? Should it stay, or become a synonym of [winapi]? Or just burninated altogether?</strike>

Comment: Seems like a pointless tag.  I don't see how it relates to this question at all, nor do I see how it could be helpful for any question ever, really.

Comment: @Servy in that case, should I just go ahead and make a burninate request?

Comment: Burn it[.](http://burnthatmothertrucker.com)

Comment: @Will Are you allowed to burninate sponsored tags?

Comment: In this case the author was wrong. It's since been edited again by someone else, and a comment left.

Comment: I can't see the point of it. Nor, apparently, could its wiki excerpt author.

Comment: You haven't shown why questions relating to MSDN articles shouldn't have an MSDN tag. Sure there's not many of them, but why wouldn't you tag them with that? If you can explain then you'll get my vote.

Comment: @slugster Ok, I've updated it - and yes, I can imagine a *few* questions that could have [msdn] and be on-topic, but certainly not 7000 of them.

Comment: @AstroCB probably not.  That tag isn't sponsored, however, so the question is moot.

Comment: @Will http://i.stack.imgur.com/qAWDV.jpg

Comment: I believe there can be some questions regarding the (sometimes) horrible explanation **msdn** gives.. But still, those could be generalised to : "What does `X`function?"

Comment: @AstroCB Hmmm, not sure of the distinction, but I thought you were referring to a Sponsored Tag, like [tag:andorid], which has an image.  The msdn tag isn't sponsored in this way.  I don't see any "sponsored links" on msdn at all.  I also haven't heard of sponsored links for tags, so I'm completely ignorant of the subject.  Would be a good question for the team, tho...

Comment: @Will love the [tag:andorid] ;-)

Comment: @slugster Rather than asking why a tag *shouldn't* be included, we should ask why a tag *should* be included. If the only reason for adding the tag is because the question is about an MSDN article, then that's no good reason at all. Tags are supposed to cue people in to questions related to languages or topics on which they are Subject-Matter Experts (or at least can contribute). MSDN articles, however, are just articles about specific topics/languages. Can anyone really claim to be a meta expert on meta articles? To me MSDN clearly doesn't deserve to be a tag.

Comment: @Will I'm not sure, but it [is sponsored](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/258672) (see #1).

Comment: @AstroCB eh, that specifically mentions image branding, which is specifically not happening on the MSDN tag.  They got the links (I guess; I still don't see them for some reason), but not the image.  Or  does it have an image that I'm not seeing either?  Weird.  Anyhow, somebody @ me if someone on the team answers these questions...

Comment: @Will It may have something to do with rep (further reduced advertising like you get at 200?), but I see the links. (Also, you don't have to have *all* of those options; a tag can have any of the three.)

Comment: @Will It appears that the [semi-official response](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/burninate-sponsored-tags) is that you *can*, but that it (obviously) removes SE revenue, so it's better if you didn't. Also, [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2303511#2303511) may be why you don't see the sponsored links.